# How do I change the actual X server keyboard layout keys?

Tags: linux, xorg, keyboard-layout

I use Swedish(Dvorak) as keyboard layout on Ubuntu.

I bought a new keyboard and with the current layout I miss the pipe key. I want to change one of my keys to produce a pipe instead of it's ordinary key. Is there a file that contains all the current mappings? Should I not be able to change for instance keycode X to produce the pipe instead of keycode Y?

I do not mind hard coding the Swedish(Dvorak) file as it is just one row I want to change. I would also *not* want any hack that requires more software or other dependencies, I just want to change that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and used [`xmodmap`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.2.0/xmodmap.1.html) like that to start `bc` with `.`, rather than `,` in the number block:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = period period" && bc
xmodmap -e "keycode 91 = KP_Delete KP_Separator"
```

The first symbol is for normal key press, the second with shift.

You can use xmodmap in your startup scripts. The symbol for `|` is `bar`.
Keycode for `|` is on my (german) layout 94.

You can find out what the keycode for your keys is with [`xev`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html). It will open a small box and you see the keypress (and mouse) events in the terminal.